# In prolog, how can I contiune after fail in a rule?

Tags: prolog

I have list of pairs such [[1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [2,1], [2,2], ...]

```
function([[H1, H2| _]|Rest]):-
    conflicts(H1,H2),
    write('conflict: '), write(H1), writeln(H2),
    function(Rest).
function([]).
```

I can take "1" as H1 and "2" as H2.

`conflict` rule makes comparison according some rules, it works okay.

"1" and "2" conflicts. So `conflicts` return `true` and it writes "conflict 1 2" at first iteration.

"1" and "3" doesn't conflict. So `conflicts` return `false` at second iteration.

As you expected, the call ends with `false`.

I want to continue to third iteration and fourth and fifth and ... . If third pair conflicts, it will write; otherwise, it will continue without writing.

How can I do that?
Thanks alot.

Comment: Just a notational point: If you have "pairs" you can just say, `[H1,H2]`. You don't need `[H1,H2|_]` since the tail will be `[]`. And @PauloMoura made a point showing some more efficient alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Prolog's if-then-else control construct:

```
function([[H1, H2| _]|Rest]):-
    (   conflicts(H1,H2) ->
        write('conflict: '), write(H1), writeln(H2)
    ;   true
    ),
    function(Rest).
function([]).
```

Btw, to represent pairs, a representation such as `H1-H2` or `(H1, H2)` would be more efficient than using a list as `[H1, H2]` is just syntactic sugar for `'.'(H1, '.'(H2, []))`.